# I need help getting started with this one please (confusing Advanced Linear Algebra Problem)

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, projection

This one has most of us in class scratching our heads. I not looking for a full solution, just a way to get started.  If I can get the form for P I think I can get it from there.  Here's the problem:

[image]

I did find a solution online, but I didn't understand it, so it's not really useful to me.  They started like this

[image]

But I don't understand how they got that nor how they used it in the rest of their solution.  (Judging by the rest of the solution, I think that last isn't x^n but x^T ... I think - handwriting).

Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a vector $y$ which doesn't belong to Col(X) then $Xw = y$ has not an exact solution. Thus we look for $Xw = \bar y$ where $\bar y$ is the projection of $y$ in $Col(X)$.

The error is $e=y-\bar y=y-Xw$ and it is miminized when $e$ is orthogonal to $Col(X)$ that is

$$X^Te=X^T(y-Xw)=0\implies X^Ty=X^TXw\implies w=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$

and therefore

$$\bar y=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty=Py$$

and the projection is orthogonal since $P^T=P$.

Take also a look to this reference by MIT [Projection](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projections-onto-subspaces/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.2sum.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, we also found a wiki page and a pdf from Harvard that helped as well.  I think we've got it now.  I love this site.

Comment: @DanaHill Well done! You are welcome! Bye